# Install employer self signed certificate in Firefox

Tags: firefox, ssl

My employer has a self signed certificate and is doing a man in the middle attack to monitor all web traffic. They installed these certificates automatically on our machines and everything works fine. But, I created an Ubuntu VM and all SSL traffic on Firefox is broken with the `SEC_ERROR_UNKNOWN_ISSUER` error code.

How can I get Firefox to recognize this certificate for all websites?

Comment: "How can I get Firefox to recognize this certificate for all websites?" - Have you installed the certificates in question to the Firefox certificate store?  Hopefully you have authorization to use Ubuntu at work.

Comment: Cannot find instructions on how to do that properly. I saved the PEM certificate (which I needed to appease the Ubuntu certificate authority) and attempted to import that into Firefox's Authorities as suggested in a help article and got the error `this is not a certificate authority certificate`.

Comment: You are installing it to the wrong Firefox certificate store.

Comment: You really should seek assistance from your IT Administrator.

Comment: @harrymc, which certificate store should be used? It shouldn't go under `My Certificates`, as that is a cert that identifies me. It shouldn't go under `Servers`, since that is only adding an exception for a URL, and this is for all URLs. It shouldn't go under `People`, because that just doesn't make sense. The only one that is sensible is `Authorities`, but I get the error Steve mentioned above.

Comment: @jeremysprofile: In Firefox you should use "Your cerificates" or "People". If not enough, you can [make Firefox use operating system certificates](https://support.umbrella.com/hc/en-us/articles/115000669728-Configuring-Firefox-to-use-the-Windows-Certificate-Store).